# Using Python unittest, how can I ensure that a Class was instantiated?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Given the following:

```
class toTest(object)
    def createObject(self):
        self.created = toCreate()

class toCreate(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

# testFile.py
import unittest
class TestThing(unittest.TestCase):
    def testCreated(self):
        creator = toTest()
        toTest.createObject()
        # -- Assert that the 'toCreate' object was in fact instantiated
```

...how can I ensure that `toCreate` was in fact created? I have tried the following:

```
def testCreated(self):
    created = MagicMock(spec=toCreate)
    toTest.createObject()
    created.__init__.assert_called_once_with()
```

But I get the following error: `AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'init'`. Am I misusing the MagicMock class, and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

[`unitetest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) have two main duties:

- Define `Mock` objects: objects that are designed to follow your screenplay and record every access to your mocked object
- Patch references and recover the original state

In your example you need both functionalities: Patching `toCreate` a class reference by a mock where you can have complete behavior control. There are a lot of ways to use [`patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-patchers), some [details to take care on how use it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) and [caveats to know](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#autospeccing).

In your case you should `patch` `toCreate` a class instance and check if you call the `Mock` that `patch` used to replace the constructor:

```
class TestThing(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("module_where_toCreate_is.toCreate")
    def testCreated(self, mock_toCreate):
        creator = toTest()
        toTest.createObject()
        mock_toCreate.assert_called_with()
```